# Is their a way to get all keys from angular-translate translations?

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-translate

I want to know if there is a way to get available languages from `$translate` service and if there is a way display all the keys available in it.

I want to write a small tool that can shows easily differences between multiple translation resources files (json files).

`i18n/fr.json`

```
{
  "title": "Mon titre",
  "summary": "Mon beau résumé",
  "submit": "Envoyer!" 
}
```

`i18n/en.json`

```
{
  "title": "My title",
  "summary": "My summary",
  "submit": "Submit!",
  "contact": "Contact"
}
```

At the end, I want something like that :

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════╗
║     keys     ║     en      ║       fr        ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ home.contact ║ Contact     ║ ############### ║
║ home.submit  ║ Submit!     ║ Envoyer!        ║
║ home.summary ║ My  summary ║ Mon beau résumé ║
║ home.title   ║ My title    ║ Mon titre       ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is

```
$translateProvider.translations();
```

You should get something like the folllowing (as JSON)

```
{  
   "en":{  
      "PAGE.MAIN":"Main page",
      "PAGE.1":"Content page 1",
      "PAGE.2":"Content page 2"
   },
   "fi":{  
      "PAGE.MAIN":"Pääsivu",
      "PAGE.1":"Sisältösivu 1",
      "PAGE.2":"Sisältösivu 2"
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got something like `$translateProviderProvider is not defined`, cause I inject `$translateProvider` to my controller... any suggestion?

Comment: You can use provider only in `config` phase.

Comment: Yeah, I know, what do you recommand to allow access to this json from my controller? some custom service?

Comment: You using `$stateProvider` or some... I can put up an example.

Comment: Oh yeah! great idea, I'll do that with $stateProvider :)